# How do I copy a pointer in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I want to malloc some memory, run some operations on that memory, and then have the result of those operations be persistent. An example might be if I have a 2-d persistent array that I want to do row-wise updates on.

```
void update(int **persistent, int row, int rowSize) 
{
    int *temp = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * rowSize);
    //...do stuff with temp
    persistent[row] = temp
}
```

What would be the safest way to do this in C without having to deep-copy the contents of temp to persistent[row]? If I do it the way I typed above without freeing temp, would that cause a memory leak even if I correctly free persistent later on?

EDIT: A related question I have is: if I try to free(temp) at the end of the function, I noticed that even though persistent[row] maintains a reference to the data at temp, the memory is released. Is this because of the way malloc/free are designed, so that whenever a free on a pointer is called, the memory is freed without checking for other live references to that memory?

Comment: Why don't you just mutate persistent[row] as you go?

Comment: @Leafy There is already data in persistent[row] when it enters the function and I need to combine that initial data and a mutated version of persistent[row] to form the final persistent[row]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would only cause a memory leak if you don't properly free the old pointer that was in `persistent[row]`, if it wasn't NULL. As long as you free the old pointer before overwriting it with `temp` you won't have any problems as  long as you correctly (row by row) free `persistent`.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't cause a memory leak, since if you correctly free all of the rows separately when you free persistent then the section of memory that temp was pointing to in the code block above would also be freed.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't cause a memory leak, as free() will free the memory sector pointed by persistent, which is the same pointed by temp.